# Excel VBA Userform login with username and password on server

Tags: excel, vba, authentication

I have a userform where the user can enter username and password. I found the code here [Excel VBA & UserForm Login and Password VLOOKUP Table in Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346120/excel-vba-userform-login-and-password-vlookup-table-in-sheet)

```
Private Sub LogIn_Click()
    Dim Username As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim passWs As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim CorrectDetails As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer


    Username = Me.Username.Text

    Password = Me.Password.Text

    If Len(Trim(Username)) = 0 Then
        Me.Username.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Username", vbOKOnly, "Username"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Len(Trim(Password)) = 0 Then
        Me.Password.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Password", vbOKOnly, "Password"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set passWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Users")

    With passWs
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If UCase(Trim(.Range("B" & i).Value)) = UCase(Trim(Username)) Then '<~~ Username Check
                If .Range("C" & i).Value = Password Then '<~~ Password Check
                    CorrectDetails = True
                    Unload Me
                    MsgBox "Välkommen " & Username


                    Sheets("Start").Activate

                    '~~> Admin is True
                    If .Range("D" & i).Value = "True" Then
                        '
                        '~~> Do what you want
                        '
                    Else
                        '
                        '~~> Do what you want
                        '
                    End If

                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        '~~> Incorrect Username/Password
        If CorrectDetails = False Then
            MsgBox "Felaktivt användarnamn och/eller lösenord"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I also have a function I found at https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/86714-vba-read-text-file-from-a-url

```
Function GetFromWebpage(URL As String) As String
On Error GoTo Err_GetFromWebpage

Dim objWeb As Object
Dim strXML As String

' Instantiate an instance of the web object
Set objWeb = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

' Pass the URL to the web object, and send the request
objWeb.Open "GET", URL, False
objWeb.send

' Look at the HTML string returned
strXML = objWeb.responsetext

GetFromWebpage = strXML


End_GetFromWebpage:
' Clean up after ourselves!
Set objWeb = Nothing
Exit Function

Err_GetFromWebpage:
' Just in case there's an error!
MsgBox Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ")"
Resume End_GetFromWebpage
End Function
```

And the function is called:

```
Sub MainSub()
Dim MyString As String, s As String

MyString = GetFromWebpage("http://127.0.0.1/test3.csv")

s = MyString
Debug.Print s
End sub
```

The contents of my .csv file is:

```
Username;Password
User1;123
User2;333
```

I am trying to split mystring into username and password pairs and then check in my login form if the username and password entered is the same as on the server.

Comment: Do you have a question? What is it? What isn't working with the above? Which line? Any error messages?

Comment: I am asking how I can split the string MyString which contains the values of my test3.csv file into username and password pairs. The contents of my .csv file shows the debug.print s. After they are split I want to check in the userform if the username and password entered are the same as on the server. There are no error messages.

Comment: Load the login column data from the CSV into an array. Loop that array and split the value at each index on ";". Then the (0) position will be the username and the (1) position be the password. Pass those to your login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you with the obtaining the usernames and passwords part:

You could use the text to columns functionality in Excel to split into two columns and then loop those. However, I would read the CSV column A info into an array and  then loop the array. Use the `Split` function with delimiter `";"` to generate your pairs, assign the values from the split to password and username variables and then use those for your testing.

Example that needs adapting below:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, loginDetails(), currentLogin As Long, pairs() As String, lastRow As Long
    Set ws = Workbooks("name of CSV").Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<==change this to the open CSV name
    Dim pword As String, username As String
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow = 1 Then                      '<change to 2 if header present
            ReDim loginDetails(1, 1): loginDetails(1, 1) = .Range("A1").Value '<= change this to A2 if header
        Else
            loginDetails = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value 'Change to A2: if header present
        End If
        For currentLogin = LBound(loginDetails, 1) To UBound(loginDetails, 1)
            pword = vbNullString: username = vbNullString
            If InStr(loginDetails(currentLogin, 1), ";") > 0 Then
                pairs = Split(loginDetails(currentLogin, 1), ";")
                username = pairs(0)
                pword = pairs(1)
                'Debug.Print username, pword
                'other code to test login

            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will get right on it trying to adapt the code!

Comment: No worries :-) Any problems let me know.

Comment: I am not getting anywhere, most examples I can find open the .csv file in Excel. Could you give me some more pointers on where to go? I am looking at split and split with ;.

Comment: I assumed you were using Excel to open. How are you planning on opening and where are you running this code from?

Comment: I am thinking that this code will run in the background, so that when a user opens the workbook I get the .csv with username and password in the background and then check if a username and password combination is correct. Perhaps this is a bad way of doing it? Should I just store the usernames and passwords in the workbook?

Comment: Are you trying to use the csv to validate what the user enters? If so, depending on the experience of your users, is there any reason not to keep the data to check against in a very hidden sheet and lock your vbe project with a password to your basic users won't be able to unhide and view.

Comment: Yes, if the user enters username User1 and password 123 I am trying to check those values against the values in the .csv file. Yes, I am thinking that I can add/remove users from the server without having access to the file!

Comment: The original source of your code uses this idea of looking up within a sheet. So make the sheet very hidden (I think you can look up against a very hidden sheet) and then lock your project.

Comment: Ok, perhaps you are correct. I guess I could add a lot of users and passwords and then distribute them accordingly. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Excel is not particularly secure. The other alternative is validating against a database but then people need read access to the database etc and just becomes more complicated.